# BibTex Style File for UWE Harvard

Tags: bibtex, harvard-style

In 2011 the University of the West of England developed its own version of the Harvard referencing system [1].
Unfortunately they do not officially support BibTex and therefore do not provide a bst file.

I was wondering if any former or current student has created such a file and is willing to share it.

[1] http://www1.uwe.ac.uk/students/studysupport/studyskills/referencing/uweharvard.aspx

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Judging from the many entry types that are mentioned in the guide booklet (including Acts of Parliament, audio/video, blogs, datasets, FaceBook entries [!], House of Commons/Lords reports, live dances, live plays, patents, photographs, etc. etc.) it would seem to be rather advantageous to implement this in `biblatex` rather than by setting up a BibTeX `.bst` (bibliography style) file. The "harvard" part of the assignment would seem to be a rather straightforward authoryear style citation system with first and middle names abbreviated down to first initials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `biblatex` it is not too hard to define this citation style.
I was not to keen to implement all 95 (!) different entry types, but `@book`, `@inbook`, `@collection`, `@incollection`, `@article` and `@online` should work.

The basis is the standard `authoryear` style.

Load `biblatex` with `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxnames=999, maxcitenames=3, firstinits=true, urldate=long]{biblatex}` and add this to your preamble

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{%
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {\ifnumequal{#1}{1}%
     {}%
     {\mkbibordedition{#1}~\bibstring{edition}}%
    }
    {#1\isdot}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection]{title}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection]{citetitle}{#1\isdot}

\newrobustcmd{\MakeTitleCase}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifentrytype{article}} or test {\ifentrytype{inbook}} or test {\ifentrytype{incollection}}}
    {#1}
    {\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibsentence\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
    {}
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}}
       \ifboolexpr{
         not test {\iffieldundef{url}}
         or
         not test {\iffieldundef{urldate}}
         or
         not test {\iffieldundef{doi}}
         or
         not test {\iffieldundef{eprint}}
       }
         {\nopunct\bibstring[\mkbibbrackets]{online}}%
         {}}}

\newbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\NewBibliographyString{online}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  urlseen    = {accessed},
  online     = {online},
}
```

Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxnames=999, maxcitenames=3, firstinits=true, urldate=long]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{%
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {\ifnumequal{#1}{1}%
     {}%
     {\mkbibordedition{#1}~\bibstring{edition}}%
    }
    {#1\isdot}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection]{title}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection]{citetitle}{#1\isdot}

\newrobustcmd{\MakeTitleCase}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifentrytype{article}} or test {\ifentrytype{inbook}} or test {\ifentrytype{incollection}}}
    {#1}
    {\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibsentence\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
    {}
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}}
       \ifboolexpr{
         not test {\iffieldundef{url}}
         or
         not test {\iffieldundef{urldate}}
         or
         not test {\iffieldundef{doi}}
         or
         not test {\iffieldundef{eprint}}
       }
         {\nopunct\bibstring[\mkbibbrackets]{online}}%
         {}}}

\newbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\NewBibliographyString{online}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  urlseen    = {accessed},
  online     = {online},
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{PearECP,
  author    = {Alan Pearson and John Field and Zoe Jordan},
  title     = {Evidence-Based Clinical Practice in Nursing and Health Care},
  subtitle  = {Assimilating Research, Experience and Expertise},
  year      = {2007},
  publisher = {Blackwell},
  address   = {Oxford},
  edition   = {2},
}
@article{LangLC,
  author    = {Langman, S. and Smith, J. and Athens, D.A. and Gibbs, Y.},
  title     = {Life cycles: manufacturing techniques in the new millennium},
  year      = {2000},
  journal   = {Manufacturing Weekly},
  volume    = {15},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {12-18},
}
@article{KellTFAC,
  author    = {Bridget Kelly and Jason C.G. Halford and Emma J. Boyland and Kathy Chapman and Inmaculada Bautista-Castano and Christina Berg and Margherita Caroli and Brian Cook and Janine G. Coutinho and Tobias Effertz and Evangelia Grammatikaki and Kathleen Keller and Raymond Leung and Yannis Manios and Renata Monteiro and Claire Pedley and Hillevi Prell and Kim Raine and Elisabetta Recine and Lluis Serra-Majem and Sonia Singh and Carolyn Summerbell},
  title     = {Television Food Advertising to Children},
  subtitle  = {A Global Perspective},
  date      = {2010-09},
  journal   = {American Journal of Public Health},
  volume    = {100},
  number    = {9},
  pages     = {1730–-1736},
  doi       = {10.2105/AJPH.2009.179267},
  urldate   = {2013-09-28},
}
@online{RCN,
  author    = {{Royal College of Nursing}},
  title     = {Learning and Education},
  date      = {2009},
  url       = {http://www.rcn.org.uk/development/learning},
  urldate   = {2010-12-22},
}
@incollection{CarNaM,
  title     = {Nursing and Medicine},
  author    = {Havi Carel},
  editor    = {Sebastian Luft and Soren Overgaard},
  booktitle = {The Routledge Companion to Phenomenology},
  date      = {2011},
  publisher = {Routledge},
  location  = {London},
  chapter   = {57},
}
@collection{BoxSE,
  title     = {Sports Ethics},
  subtitle  = {An Anthology},
  editor    = {Jan Boxill},
  date      = {2003},
  publisher = {Blackwell},
  location  = {Oxford},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
  Citations \parencite{wilde}, \parencite{herrmann} and \parencite{baez/article}
  The Greek philosophers must have known something \parencite{aristotle:anima}.
  Again \parencite{westfahl:space} and \parencite{angenendt} and \parencite{companion}.
  \nocite{PearECP,LangLC,KellTFAC,RCN,CarNaM,knuth:ct,nietzsche:ksa,BoxSE}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! I did not know about BibLaTex before.
I have to try it out.

Comment: @Lorenz Give it a try! I hope to find time tomorrow to add some explaining words to the code above. If you find anything not working correctly, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think using biblatex is a great idea in this case. That is why I accepted moewe's answer.
However, I have not yet confirmed whether or not his code produces the correct style.

In case somebody wants to stick with plain BibTex I tried creating a style via `latex makebst`. I uploaded the result with some commentary [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/i3cxt30xsn9ox3o/uwe_harvard-20130926.zip?dl=1).

Comment: Did you manage to implement "print edition only if not 1st"? And the differing use of Title Case v. Sentence case in titles?

Comment: @moewe no I think I missed those subtleties. I'm going to focus on the biblatex now.